# Communicating with a HTTP server

Tags: c#, http, sockets

I'm currently trying to program my own HttpWebRequest class. I've already written the code that sends the header and the body of the request to the server and awaits a response. However, I am unsure which charset I should use for the header.

I've also been wondering what would be a good way of processing the response (header + body). Should I try to decode all received data into a string, or should I do it differently? I was thinking of splitting the header from the body using the two line feeds/carriage returns that separate those two parts. Then I would be able to decode the header and leave the body for later, when I know its charset.

So my questions in short:

What charset does HTTP use for its headers?
What's a good way of processing the response?

Comment: More details, may you please put what you have?

Comment: Keep in mind HTTP != HTML. Do not attempt to parse the body into a string -- what if you get back a 300MB video file with chunked encoding? My advice would be to buffer the response into memory (as raw bytes) as it comes in, and expose that to your clients.

Comment: Yup. Although I do need to parse the header into a string. But what encoding does the header use? Code is on its way, I'm trying to modify it a bit though.

Comment: I've been doing some more research. Turns out there's no need to write an HTTP class. The main reason why I wanted to do it was HttpWebRequest's apparent slowness. Although I've figured out that setting its proxy to null solves that problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I would recommend that you become intimately familiar with [RFC-2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) which is the RFC for the HTTP 1.1 protocol.

From the above RFC you will find the following statement

> The TEXT rule is only used for descriptive field contents and values
> that are not intended to be interpreted by the message parser. Words
> of *TEXT MAY contain characters from character sets other than ISO-
> 8859-1 [22] only when encoded according to the rules of RFC 2047
> [14].

The headers should use ISO-8859-1 encoding unless encoded using the MIME encoding outlined in RFC-2047.

As for the parsing of the response, that really depends on the message. Personally, I would processes the response based on the BNF defined for HTTP as I identify tokens that I recognize I would update the state of the parser to process the rest of the response accordingly. For example as the response data is processed you might find that the response is a JPG image and the the content length is X, so you can setup the appropriate memory stream to read the content into and then create an Image etc.